# How to get a file using post request on Django - upload file via HTML

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a model called ImageFile, with a field Image = models.IamgeField()
and I have this on my template:

```
<form action="." method="POST>
  <label for="img">Select image:</label>
  <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

How can I save this image which I get from the template?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the question is. Are you asking how do you save the image from the form being submitted or how do you access the image once it's stored?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a [model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) and next you need to configure the view to use the form. Here are some examples [FormView1](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/) [FormView2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/django-modelform-create-form-from-models/). Once the view is set use its context to display the form in the template